# Trying to post multi-form with PNG C#

Tags: c#, winforms, post, request

Trying to post a multi-form with a PNG image.

Took cookie out for security. The response we get is just the web page, no actions taken or anything, obviously did not post correctly when we check the uploaded area of the site.

Here is the raw HTML as requested:

```
<form action="/build/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="zLrU9MsixdrkkifJ7aEhOEGvKD0KL5nxaBcEVVukbbc5tKSWHo8xwDabXcSgRD5svi0uudzRyAAPRH7AfBKNlyx9yC81"> 
<input id="assetTypeId" name="assetTypeId" type="hidden" value="2"> 
<input id="isOggUploadEnabled" name="isOggUploadEnabled" type="hidden" value="True"> 
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsTgaUploadEnabled field is required." id="isTgaUploadEnabled" name="isTgaUploadEnabled" type="hidden" value="True"> 
<input id="groupId" name="groupId" type="hidden"> 
<input id="onVerificationPage" name="onVerificationPage" type="hidden" value="False"> 
<input id="captchaEnabled" name="captchaEnabled" type="hidden" value="False"><div id="container">
<div class="form-row">
<label for="file">Find your image:</label> 
<input id="file" type="file" name="file" tabindex="1"> 
<span id="file-error" class="error"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
<label for="name"> Name:</label> 
<input id="name" type="text" class="text-box text-box-medium" name="name" maxlength="50" tabindex="2"> 
<span id="name-error" class="error"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-row submit-buttons">
<a id="upload-button" class="btn-medium btn-primary btn-level-element" tabindex="4">Upload</a> 
<span id="loading-container">
<img src="https://images.rbxcdn.com/ec4e85b0c4396cf753a06fade0a8d8af.gif"></span>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the upload.cs class:

```
// /*!
//  * Project: Salient.Web.HttpLib
//  * http://salient.codeplex.com
//  *
//  * Date: April 11 2010 
//  */

#region

using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

#endregion

/// <summary>
/// This class contains methods excepted from Salient.Web.HttpLib.HttpRequestUtility
/// for demonstration purposes. Please see http://salient.codeplex.com for full 
/// implementation
/// </summary>
public static class Upload
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Uploads a stream using a multipart/form-data POST.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requestUri"></param>
    /// <param name="postData">A NameValueCollection containing form fields 
    /// to post with file data</param>
    /// <param name="fileData">An open, positioned stream containing the file data</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">Optional, a name to assign to the file data.</param>
    /// <param name="fileContentType">Optional. 
    /// If omitted, registry is queried using <paramref name="fileName"/>. 
    /// If content type is not available from registry, 
    /// application/octet-stream will be submitted.</param>
    /// <param name="fileFieldName">Optional, 
    /// a form field name to assign to the uploaded file data. 
    /// If omitted the value 'file' will be submitted.</param>
    /// <param name="cookies">Optional, can pass null. Used to send and retrieve cookies. 
    /// Pass the same instance to subsequent calls to maintain state if required.</param>
    /// <param name="headers">Optional, headers to be added to request.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// Reference: 
    /// http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1867
    /// http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2388
    /// http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2
    /// 
    public static WebResponse PostFile
    (Uri requestUri, NameValueCollection postData, Stream fileData, string fileName,
             string fileContentType, string fileFieldName, CookieContainer cookies,
    NameValueCollection headers, WebBrowser browser)
    {
        try

        {
            HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

            string ctype;

            fileContentType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileContentType)
                                  ? TryGetContentType(fileName, out ctype) ?
                    ctype : "application/octet-stream"
                                  : fileContentType;

            fileFieldName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileFieldName) ? "file" : fileFieldName;

            if (headers != null)
            {
                // set the headers
                foreach (string key in headers.AllKeys)
                {
                    string[] values = headers.GetValues(key);
                    if (values != null)
                        foreach (string value in values)
                        {
                            webrequest.Headers.Add(key, value);
                        }
                }
            }
            webrequest.Method = "POST";

            if (cookies != null)
            {
                webrequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
            }

            string boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString
                        ("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            webrequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

            StringBuilder sbHeader = new StringBuilder();

            // add form fields, if any
            if (postData != null)
            {
                foreach (string key in postData.AllKeys)
                {
                    string[] values = postData.GetValues(key);
                    if (values != null)
                        foreach (string value in values)
                        {
                            sbHeader.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
                            sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}\r\n", key,
                                                  value);
                        }
                }
            }

            if (fileData != null)
            {
                sbHeader.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\n", boundary);
                sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Disposition: form-data; z1name=\"{0}\"; {1}\r\n", fileFieldName,
                                      string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)
                                          ?
                                              ""
                                          : string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "filename=\"{0}\";",
                                                          Path.GetFileName(fileName)));

                sbHeader.AppendFormat("Content-Type: {0}\r\n\r\n", fileContentType);
            }

            byte[] header = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sbHeader.ToString());
            byte[] footer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
            long contentLength = header.Length + (fileData != null ?
                fileData.Length : 0) + footer.Length;

            webrequest.ContentLength = contentLength;

            using (Stream requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);


                if (fileData != null)
                {
                    // write the file data, if any
                    byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096,
                        (int)fileData.Length))];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = fileData.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }

                // write footer
                requestStream.Write(footer, 0, footer.Length);
                var wr = webrequest.GetResponse();
                var pageContent = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream())
                         .ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(pageContent);
                browser.DocumentText = pageContent;
                return wr;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            var pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                          .ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(pageContent);
            browser.DocumentText = pageContent;
            return null;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uploads a file using a multipart/form-data POST.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requestUri"></param>
    /// <param name="postData">A NameValueCollection containing 
    /// form fields to post with file data</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">The physical path of the file to upload</param>
    /// <param name="fileContentType">Optional. 
    /// If omitted, registry is queried using <paramref name="fileName"/>. 
    /// If content type is not available from registry, 
    /// application/octet-stream will be submitted.</param>
    /// <param name="fileFieldName">Optional, a form field name 
    /// to assign to the uploaded file data. 
    /// If omitted the value 'file' will be submitted.</param>
    /// <param name="cookies">Optional, can pass null. Used to send and retrieve cookies. 
    /// Pass the same instance to subsequent calls to maintain state if required.</param>
    /// <param name="headers">Optional, headers to be added to request.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static WebResponse PostFile
    (Uri requestUri, NameValueCollection postData, string fileName,
         string fileContentType, string fileFieldName, CookieContainer cookies,
         NameValueCollection headers, WebBrowser browser)
    {
        using (FileStream fileData = File.Open
        (fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            return PostFile(requestUri, postData, fileData,
        fileName, fileContentType, fileFieldName, cookies,
                            headers, browser);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to query registry for content-type of supplied file name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <param name="contentType"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool TryGetContentType(string fileName, out string contentType)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey
                (@"MIME\Database\Content Type");

            if (key != null)
            {
                foreach (string keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                {
                    RegistryKey subKey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
                    if (subKey != null)
                    {
                        string subKeyValue = (string)subKey.GetValue("Extension");

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subKeyValue))
                        {
                            if (string.Compare(Path.GetExtension
                (fileName).ToUpperInvariant(),
                                     subKeyValue.ToUpperInvariant(),
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ==
                                0)
                            {
                                contentType = keyName;
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // ReSharper disable EmptyGeneralCatchClause
        catch
        {
            // fail silently
            // TODO: rethrow registry access denied errors
        }
        // ReSharper restore EmptyGeneralCatchClause
        contentType = "";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the Form.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Clothing_Uploader___CEFSharp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //   CefSettings s = new CefSettings();
            //    Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();
            ///      Cef.Initialize();

        }

        private  void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //var url = "http://api.roblox.com/My/Balance";
            string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:/Users/Kyle/Desktop/841898120.png");

            // this represents fields from a form
            NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection();
            //postData.Add("fieldName", "fieldValue");



            // this could be an existing CookieContainer used in a previous request
            // to contain session or other cookies. Typically used to maintain
            // session state across several requests.
            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            cookies.Add(new Uri("https://www.roblox.com/"), new Cookie(".ROBLOSECURITY", ""));

            //// end
            HttpClientHandler h = new HttpClientHandler();
            h.CookieContainer = cookies;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(h);
            var response2 = client.GetAsync("https://roblox.com/build/upload").Result;
            var resultContent = response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            String rvt = GetRequestVerificationToken(resultContent);
            Console.WriteLine("token: " + rvt);
            /// end

            postData.Add("__RequestVerificationToken", rvt);
            postData.Add("assetTypeId", "12");
            postData.Add("isOggUploadEnabled", "True");
            postData.Add("isTgaUploadEnabled", "True");
            postData.Add("groupId", "3656996");
            postData.Add("name", "Jeffery StarS");
            postData.Add("onVerificationPage", "False");
            postData.Add("captchaEnabled", "False");

            // you can send additional request headers with the headers collection
            NameValueCollection headers = new NameValueCollection();

           // headers.Add("x-headerName", "header value");

            // content type of the posted file.
            // if null, the content type will be determined by the filename.
            // defaults to application/octet-stream
            const string fileContentType = "png ";

            // the key used to identify this file. typically unused.
            // if null, 'file' will be submitted.
            const string fileFieldName = "file";

            string responseText;
           WebResponse response = Upload.PostFile(new Uri("https://roblox.com/build/upload/"), 
        postData, filePath, fileContentType, fileFieldName,
                            cookies, headers, webBrowser1);
            try

            {

                if (response != null)
                {
                    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    Console.WriteLine(r.ReadToEnd());

                }
            }
            catch (WebException wex)
            {
                var pageContent = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                                      .ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(pageContent);
            }

        }
        public string GetRequestVerificationToken(String find)
        {
            String val = "name=__RequestVerificationToken";
            String readInto = "";
            int startRead = find.IndexOf(val, 0) + val.Length + 20;


            while (find[startRead] != '>')
            {
                readInto += find[startRead];
                ++startRead;
            }

            return readInto;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your form HTML? When posting a question here, make sure to provide a complete example so we can have all of the information to better understand what is going on in the code.

Comment: @NickGasiaRobitsch I added the HTML form for more context

Comment: `var response2 = client.GetAsync("https://roblox.com/build/upload").Result;` This is a post request, not a get request. First thing I see. Also, it looks like you are doing a get, then near the end, you do it as a post to the same endpoint. Did you intend to call this twice? Also, WebResponse is the abstract base class of HttpWebResponse, which is what I think you should be using instead.

Comment: @NickGasiaRobitsch We use the POST request first to grab the __RequestVerificationToken, and the second to POST the data to the endpoint as to submit it.

Comment: Right, look at the `Form_Load()` method you are doing a 'GET' then later a 'POST', but you do not have separate methods defined to handle a get and post method at `/build/upload` in the code you have shown above. Those are different operation, requiring different endpoints. But you are sending them to the same endpoint. That is what is confusing me. How is that part working at all? I am not a webforms/winforms developer, so just pointing out what I see. Take it for what its worth.

Comment: My point in this is, that by default, it will accept a get, but not a post. In MVC I would just put a decorator over the method as `[HttpPost]`, to designate it as a post method, and change the initial get, to a Post, so that it is consistant. Will require some logic changes to work, but I think that is your issue. Hard to tell without debugging.

Comment: @NickGasiaRobitsch The `/build/upload` endpoint supports both GET and POST requests.